# Firebase Cloud Firestore strategy for putting old posts in follower’s feeds

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, swift4, google-cloud-firestore

I’m building a social networking application that has a follower/following setup, with feeds. Currently my structure is like:

```
/posts
    {postObject}
    {postObject}
    .
    .
    .
/users
    -{$uid}
        /posts
            (Contains reference ids to this users posts)
        /followers
            (Contains reference ids to users)
        /following
            (Contains reference ids to users)
        /feed
            (Contains reference ids to user’s posts and posts of the users they follow)
     [repeated for each uid]
```

I currently already have it set up to where, when a user you follow makes a new post, a reference to that post is saved in your feed.

My questions is: **when a user follows someone with previous posts, what’s a sensible way to add the FOLLOWED user’s *previous posts* to the following user’s feed?**

My original thought was to (using Cloud Functions) write every post id of the followed user to the following user’s feed, which is a simple implementation, but seems inefficient if the followed user has tens of thousands of posts. Also, considering Firestore charges for reads and writes, it would seem incredibly expensive to perform all those reads and writes (especially if a user follows and then quickly unfollows another user). Admittedly, I’m not even sure this is how the billing for Firestore works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same issue!

Comment: @Tometoyou Sort of. I’m using a cloud function (triggered on follow event) to gather the posts of the user being followed from the last 30 days, and adding those to the feed of the follower, with a max of about 500 posts written. You could do all posts of the followed user, but from a business sense, it wasn’t practical for my purposes. It’s unlikely that a user would scroll far enough down their own feed to see more than 500 posts from one single person they follow.

Comment: @Tometoyou I found this code to be really helpful (with modifications), specifically the “getLastMonthUserPosts” function, and the function that actually calls getLastMonthUserPosts https://github.com/FrangSierra/firestore-cloud-functions-typescript/blob/master/functions/src/atomic-operations/index.ts

Comment: Thank you very much! I was thinking about doing a trigger on follow as well, good to hear that you also did the same. Very helpful to see that code too!

Comment: Did you manage to get the userId of the user who triggered the function btw?

Comment: @Tometoyou my “follows” and followers are stored in a sort of dictionary like userId: {timeStamp: 1938499393839, [otherData]}, so when a follow is triggered on a creation event at the reference “users/{followedUserId}/followers/{followingUserId}”, my cloud function gets the followedUserId from event.params.followedUserId. See Cloud Functions w/ Firestore and wildcard parameters for more detail https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions

Comment: Ah I see, thanks! How did you handle likes on posts? Because if theyre constantly updating it'll be difficult to constantly updating the like count! And what's the advantage of storing your posts in a root collection instead of just under users/{uid}/posts?

Comment: @Tometoyou likes are actually stored as “likers”, so the liker’s uid is the key to the like object. Two ways to responsibly store like count: distributed counters (see firestore docs), or, each time the post is liked, trigger an aggregating cloud function that counts the number of like documnents a post has, and sets the post like count to that number of documents. Distributed counters are the better way in the long run, but the aggregation way is “simpler” to implement.

Comment: @Tometoyou Each user has a profile, where all their posts are fetched from users/{uid}/posts. Each user also has a feed where posts from their own account, and their followers are displayed. The issue here is, when you want to retrieve a users feed, you need to get things like like count and comment count. Every time these counts change, you’d have to update the post in EVERY feed that the post is in, significantly increasing read/write costs. Instead, I stored the post ids and post dates in each user’s feed. To get the relevant data for each post from the /posts collection using the ids.

Comment: @Tometoyou this will help for future cases as well, like if you implemented editing posts or something. The actual post data is stored in one root location (“posts”). The reference id for the post is stored in relevant collections like feeds and user/{uid}/posts, instead of the entire post document. Thus, changes to posts/counts only need to be written to one place, reducing write and storage costs.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for that info! I’m looking at trying to make my feed update in real-time though, so I don’t think having a reference would work would it? Maybe if I can somehow have a listener on some like count object for a specific post in view that updates in real time then when that post is out of view it destroys the listener? I didn’t think about these downsides when I initially chose to go with firebase!

Comment: @Tometoyou It’s hard to think about that without writing the code myself haha, Firebase can definitely get challenging. But I guess it depends on what client you are writing in? For iOS/Android it could be just as simple as removing listeners when the cell is about to be destroyed/reused/going out of view. I’m sure this has been done before in another question, that could explain better than myself.

Comment: Yeah haha I’m making an iOS app in Swift! But yeah that was my thought like you were saying, destroying the listener when the cells out of view.